Axiom of choice as a property-to-set axiom in ZFC
I was studying set theory when a question came to my mind.
It is known that some axioms of the  set theory are interpretable as statements about which formulae make up a set (loosely speaking). For example, the axiom of the empty set can be phrased by saying that the formula "negation of x = x" makes up a set, viz. there exists the set of all (and only, but less relevantly due to the axiom of specification) the elements satisfying it.
I was wondering if, among the many equivalent forms of the axiom of choice, there is one which can be interpreted in this framework. It doesn't have to be necessary a first-order formula (e.g. also infinitary disjunctions could work for me), I seek for it more as a conceptual point of view, rather than for a formal usage.

The Axiom of Choice, very famously, guarantees the existence of a set, but it does not provide any description of that set, or it can describe a specific set and claim it is not empty, but will not provide any description of its possible elements.
So, for example, we can phrase the Axiom of Choice as saying that if $\varnothing\notin X$, then $\prod X\neq\varnothing$. Note that $\prod X$ is always a set, it is just a specific subset of $\mathcal P(X\times\bigcup X)$.
Or, we can say that every set can be well-ordered, which can also be restated as "the set of all well-orderings of $X$ is non-empty".
Or, we can state that if $X$ is a set whose members are pairwise disjoint and non-empty, then there is $Y$ such that $Y\cap x$ is a singleton for each $x\in X$. Again, providing us with something without an explicit sort of description. And again, we may restate this as "the set of transversals is non-empty".
To the broad question of whether we write this in such and such form, it is generally hard to provide a sufficient answer. Especially when not restricting to first-order logic (where we have easy access to tools like forcing and completeness, so we can sort of argue that the answer is negative). And by allowing infinitary logic the nature of $\sf ZFC$ changes too. But in general, there's no reason to expect any kind of specificity here. We can always add many sets which are sufficiently "indiscernible" while preserving definability properties.

At one time, I thought that AC is distinguished from the other existence axioms by asserting the existence of a set without specifying its members. Unfortunately, that idea ran into a silly counterexample. AC is equivalent to "there exists a set of all non-well-orderable sets." (I still think the original idea has some merit, but I haven't seriously looked for that merit.)

@Andreas: Of course, we can phrase it in all kind of ways like that. You can use sort of trick to make statements like "Let $\alpha$ be the least such that $V_\alpha$ is not well-orderable ..." then the Axiom of Choice proves that ${\alpha}$ is a set. But in a way this is really a convoluted contortion of statement, which if nothing else, puts our slogans of "existence without expression" into question, but the matter of fact is that the other axioms are providing us with relatively simple recipes for sets, whereas the Axiom of Choice doesn't.

That's why I said the counterexample is silly. But it would be nice to have a definition of "silly" rather than "this is obviously silly and that is obviously not silly" or "you know it when you see it."
